# python multiprocessing is slower than normal implementation

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So this is my code

```
def get_h(tmp):                                                                   
    tmp =[map(float,line.split()[3:6]) for line in tmp[:768]]
    return hbond(tmp,side)

def get_sc(tmp):
    return popvar(tmp)

def calculate():                                   
    hframe=[]
    pl=Pool() 
    s=time()                                     
    with open(file) as f:
        for _ in xrange(100):
            tmp=list(islice(f,9,9+atoms))          
            if not tmp: break
            hframe.append(pl.apply_async(get_h,[tmp]))  
    hframe=[i.get() for i in hframe]
    print time()-s   #takes ~ 1 sec

    s=time()
    ll=[pl.apply_async(get_sc,[tmp]) for tmp in izip(*hframe)]
    ll=[i.get() for i in ll]
    print time()-s #takes ~23 sec !!!

    s=time()
    ll=[get_sc(tmp) for tmp in izip(*hframe)]
    print time()-s #takes ~ 1 sec
```

The `calculate` is the main function here. It does 2 things. 1st reads a files that is divided into blocks, 2nd call another function (created from a fortran program) to do further calculation. I used python multiprocessing `pool` to read the data blocks from file. But when I use the `pool` for the calculation part it is way slower (nearly 23 times) than the normal implementation. What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Workers and the parent process do not share an address space.

So the data being processed is sent from the parent to the worker via inter process communication (a Queue).
If you have a lot of data (in your case 768 lines), this incurs a lot of overhead.

It is probably a better strategy to give each worker the boundaries of the slice to use and let the workers read from the file themselves. This way you don't need to move large amounts of data from the parent process to the workers.